# MapReduce skipping keys?

Tags: distributed, parallel-processing, mapreduce, cluster-computing, qizmt

I'm running a local, single-system test using Qizmt of a simple MapReduce operation. At the end of the 'Map' phase I am calling:

```
output.Add(rKey, rValue);
```

This is called let's say a million times, and the keys are 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc - each unique (I'm just testing, after all). I've checked that this is happening as intended. It is. The function is called a million independent times and the values input are correct.

To my surprise, in the 'Reduce' phase only, say, a hundred or so keys are actually received (that is, the 'Reduce' function is called only a hundred or so times). These keys seem to picked almost arbitrarily from the list mapped with a pattern such as the following: 0, 383, 766, 2858, 3241, 5716, etc.

The set of keys which make it through to 'Reduce' are consistent. ie. I will get 0, 383, 766, etc consistently each run of the task. However, if I add a second system to the cluster, the set of keys which make it through is changed entirely!

The stage between 'Map' and 'Reduce' is a bit of a mystery to me - and I'm really not sure where to look since my Map function appears to be behaving exactly as intended (that is, calling 'output' a million times). Does anyone with more experience of parallel processing have any idea where I should be looking, or anything that might cause this behaviour?

Comment: According to [the MapReduce Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce), the stages between Map and Reduce are Partition and Comparison. Maybe the Partition function thinks it has more than one Reducer?

Comment: Quite possibly, although Qizmt seems to abstracts the partition function out of the existence - don't know how I'd analyse it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't resolve. Ultimately wrote the project in another language and didn't encounter the same issue. Qizmt doesn't seem to be getting updated at all anyway.